# dataframe is not updated while using loc function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Here below a dataframe.

```
df_strat = pd.DataFrame({'in_pos': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0], 
                    'in': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0]})
```

I need to update the 'in' column value, either when there is a '1' in the column 'in_pos' or when there is a '1' in the previous row of the 'in' column. Same when values are -1 and -1. And I would extend to any set of value.

So I used the following code only to test '1' values:

```
df_strat.loc[(df_strat['in_pos'].shift(1) == 1) | (df_strat['in'].shift(1) == 1), 'in'] = 1
```

I expect a recursive update using the loc method.

But instead, I get only a single row update as below.

[image]

I tried the following too :

```
conditions = [
(df_strat['in_pos'] == 1) | (df_strat['in'].shift(1).fillna(0) == 1),
(df_strat['in_pos'] == -1) | (df_strat['in'].shift(1).fillna(0) == -1),
(df_strat['in_pos'] == 0) | (df_strat['in'].shift(1).fillna(0) == 0)]

df_strat['in'] = np.select(conditions, [1, -1, 0], default=df_strat['in'])
```

but result is a below

[image]

Expected result is

```
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({'in_pos': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1,0,0,0], 
                    'in': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1,-1]})
```

Can anyone help ? thks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] images are not reproducible

Comment: Ditto @mozway, and please provide what your expected output should look like formatted as a code block.

Comment: That said, given your example, it makes sense that only 1 value is updated.

Comment: @mozway you should help on cynicism forum

Comment: @gfxProg sorry? Have you tested the solution below? Did it work?

Comment: yes I did. I also looked at the numpy methods. This led me to better document my issue so that further constraints can be considered. I feel the approach isn't correct but I can't figure out why.

Comment: You showed the result that you don't want, but please show the **expected output**

Comment: is in updated question section

Answer (score 1):

`loc` doesn't work "recursively". Given your code, it's expected that only one value is changed.

If you want to recursively select the column after a `1`, this means that you want to select all columns after your condition is met **once**.

You can thus use a [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) on your boolean series:

```
cond = (df_strat['in_pos'].shift(1) == 1) | (df_strat['in'].shift(1) == 1)

# or
# cond = df_strat[['in', 'in_pos']].shift(1).eq(1).any(axis=1)

df.loc[cond.cummax(), 'in'] = 1
```

Example:

```
# input
df_strat = pd.DataFrame({'in': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                         'in_pos': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]})

# output
   in  in_pos
0   0       0
1   0       0
2   0       0
3   1       1
4   1       0
5   1       0
6   1       0
```

Comment: thks. looks good but I get stuck when in_pos change value. Let me edit the question part.

Comment: @gfxProg don't forget to provide the matching expected output for your updated input